# How do I teach Chrome's omnibar to search in Google Maps?

Tags: google-chrome, google-maps, address-bar

It seems that the only site on the web that is unavailable for search via Chrome's omnibar is Google's own Maps. Is there any way I could teach the omnibar to search Google Maps?

Comment: I was searching for the general case of how to add a search provider. I didn't find this until figuring it out on my own and searching for the now known keywords (`add search manage engine chrome tab`). My original search (`add search provider chrome`), was no help. Would you and @Sathya mind generalizing this QA?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You'll have to add a custom search engine. Click on Chrome Menu → Options → Basics → Manage Search Engines. Under Add other search engine, add the following:

- Name: Google Maps
- keyword: maps.google.com
- URL: `https://www.google.com/maps/search/%s`

Now, type `maps` (and hit tab) followed by the keyword will search for the keyword in Google Maps.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeVCL.png): [image: Screenshot of entered search engine]

Comment: A small comment on this one: setting keyword to "maps.google.com" is more like the original automatic omnibar behaviour. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea why Chrome can't just autodetect this one, like it does with all other search pages?

Comment: Thomas, Unless I'm mistaken the problem is that Google Maps doesn't support OpenSearch.

Comment: Is there any way this could be parameterized to enable searching github issues for any repo from the omnibar?

Comment: See my answer--just removing the old entry may be preferable, if applicable

Comment: I've been doing this for years, but it doesn't seem to work anymore and I cannot figure out a way that does work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was because there was a custom search engine from ages ago.

- Go to custom search engines (Chrome Menu → Settings → Search Engine → Manage Search Engines)
- Scroll to or find `maps.google.com` in the (inner) search box
- Click the more button on the far right
- Click "Remove from list"

Next time I searched on Google Maps, everything started working as expected.