# Getting chrome to distinguish between search engine query or URL entry?

Tags: google-chrome

So I use the quick search engine thing on chrome a lot.

I type "w superman" if I want to find the wikipedia article for superman and even "tfs 13323" if I want to find the work item in TFS.

The only problem is that with Google's new auto complete thing, sometimes I'll type in tfs 13030 and I'll get taken to the google search page having searched for "tfs 13030".

The only way I can get rid of this is to clear my browser history.

I guess the problem with using search and url on both the same bar is it gets confused about whether ur searching or ur entering a url.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: add tfs search as a custom search provider with tfs as the keyword. Explained here [How do I teach Chrome's omnibar to search in Google Maps?](http://superuser.com/q/374954)

Comment: @Sathya : yeah that's what I've done. The problem is it's remember the fact I've searched for something starting with tfs in the past and it's thinknig I want to search that in google instead of allowing me to search the TFS site.

Comment: hit tab after typing in tfs & it'll always search with tfs keyword instead of relying on omnibox suggestion